# How does capacitive sensing relate to the resistance of the object entering the magnetic field?

Tags: sensor, capacitive, resistivity

Example: Setting up a capacitive area and dropping resistors of different sizes into the field, how do they affect the field differently? Are several resistors accumulative? Would i be able to tell from the read out of the sensor which resistor has been dropped?

Answer (score 1):

No, the capacitive E-field would not be disturbed. Also, the resistors would not be affected.

But if it were a magnetic field, you would discover the hall-[effect](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall_effect).

Comment: "*No, the capacitive E-field would not be disturbed*", it would on a minuscule scale. It would be like making two capacitors out of one, effectively placing two in series. Meaning the capacitance would be reduced and the capacitor would be rated for a higher voltage. And whatever resistor you place would be effectively adding to the ESR - But in this case, I'll be on your side, meaning that the effects can be ignored.

Comment: Fair enough ...

Comment: Hmm, I retract my statement. It would only be true if the distance increased when you placed a resistor between the two plates. Which is not true. Whatever the effect is, it’s probably negligible.